# Flutter IOS deployment target being reset

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I am building a flutter app for IOS.

I get the error...

```
The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.1.99. (in target
    'nanopb' from project 'Pods')
```

For multiple different pods in the app. I then go and manually change the deployment targets to 10.0, and this fixes the issues.

The problem is, that these deployment target settings are being randomly reset after a time and the error comes back. Why is are these being reset from 10.0 to 8.0?

Comment: Yes I have.....

Comment: Have you found a fix for this in the meantime? Have the same

Comment: please share your solution, thx